# Prove: $f$ is increasing for every $x \in (a,b)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Question:

Let $f$ be defined in $(a, b)$ and suppose that for each interior point $x$
of $(a, b)$ there exists a 1-ball $B(x)$ in which $f$ is increasing.

**Prove:** $f$ is increasing for every $x \in (a, b)$.

***my attempt:***

Using Lindelöf theorem, I would like to find a countable open cover (ball) of an open  interval $(a,b)$ similar to the one in the solution (link at the bottom), so that for any $x,y \in (a,b)$ there will exist in ball indexed by $m,n$.

My core of proof is Ball indexed by $n$ and $n+1$ will have nonempty intersection(Right?),then i think order can transit by the point in Ball $n,n+1 
\ldots m$ .(Right?)

3. personal idea
   if i use Well-ordering theorem in $\mathbb{R}$,can i approach this problem in similar way of 2. My confusion is when encountering the ball indexed bu limit ordinal, i cant express what i think ball indexed by adjacent numbers have nonempty intersection in my solution . is there something wrong in my idea?
   by

The question is Problem 4.60, Mathematical Analysis, Apostol and personal idea
**[Given question and answer as they appear in the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erzKA.png)**

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour], and some tips on [how to ask a good question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and post [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and equations in [LaTeX/MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). If your question is easier to read and has less typos it will be more likely to get an answer.

Comment: What could "$f$ is increasing in $x \in (a,b)$" possibly mean other than what you assume? Stated like that, saying that the function is increasing *in a point* other than increasing on the domain, what should it mean?

Comment: What is a 1-ball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c \in (a,b)$ and $d=\sup \{x \in (c,b):f\, \text {is increasing in } \, (c,x)\}$. If $d<b$ use that fact that $f$ is increasing in some interval around $d$ to get a  contradiction.  If $d=b$ conclude that $f$ is increasing in $(c,d)$. A similar argument can be applied to show that $f$ is increasing in $(a,c)$. The facts that $f$ is increasing in $(c,d)$ as well as  $(a,c)$ together with the hypothesis (which says $f$ is increasing in some interval around $c$) shows that $f$ is increasing in $(a,b)$

Comment: This would have been my A. I think it is the simplest method.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f$ is not increasing.
Thus there exists some $u,v$ with $a < u < v < b$ and $f(u) \ge f(v)$.
Cover $[u,v]$ with open intervals over which $f$ is increasing.
As $[u,v]$ is connected, there is a finite overlapping sequence of such intervals with $u$ in the first and $v$ in the last.
Thus $f$ is increasing over $[u,v]$.
So $f(u) < f(v)$ which contradicts the assumption.

The answer in the link is too difficult to read because of modern  ineffectiveness of new fangled computer designs.